# Manage enable - disable nginx site by Hiera puppet?

Tags: centos, puppet, automation, hiera

i got the task to implement hiera puppet script to manage sites_enabled for nginx.

Here is my puppet script:

common.yaml

```
---
classes:
    - nginx

nginx:
    enabled:
        abc.com
        xyz.com
    disabled:
        test.com
        test2.com
```

init.pp

```
class nginx{
    create_resources("site_enabled", hiera("nginx"), {})
}

define site_enabled($name){
    file { '/etc/nginx/sites_enabled/${name}':
       ensure => 'link',
       target => '/etc/nginx/site_available/${name}',
    }
}
```

But i got the error when puppet executed:

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
> SERVER: can't convert String into Integer at
> /etc/puppet/modules/nginx/manifests/init.pp:7 on node XX

When i tried to query hiera via commandline:

> $ hiera nginx
>
> {"enabled"=>["abc.com", "xyz.com"]}

I know i have wrong some where. Please kindly correct me.
i don't understand much, how hiera query and process with array data. please point me some useful document if it is possible.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions is very similar to [Problems creating Hiera hashes for create_resources](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/1380/problems-creating-hiera-hashes-for-create_resources/), which has an answer. I'll provide a recap here.

According to the [documentation for create_resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources), the hash must be in the form `{title => {parameters} }`. You should edit your hiera data to set the parameters. Since there are none, I think it could just look like this:

common.yaml

```
---
classes:
    - nginx

nginx::enabled:
    abc.com: {}
    xyz.com: {}
nginx::disabled:
    test.com: {}
    test2.com: {}
```

Next, you need to actually load the right data from hiera. You want to load `nginx::enabled`, not all of `nginx`

init.pp

```
class nginx{
    create_resources("site_enabled", hiera("nginx::enabled"))
}

define site_enabled($name){
    file { '/etc/nginx/sites_enabled/${name}':
       ensure => 'link',
       target => '/etc/nginx/site_available/${name}',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick respond, i tried as your suggestion but i did not make it worked. i got the error "err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find data item nginx::enabled in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at /etc/puppet/module". When i queried by command line: "hiera nginx
{"enabled"=>{"abc.com"=>{}, "xyz.com"=>{}}, "disabled"=>{"test.com"=>{}, "test2.com"=>{}}}. 
hiera nginx::enabled
nil
" i use puppet 2.7.11

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in the yaml, it should be corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sciunus for your quick respond.

May i ask for this question?
i would like to make my yaml data following this kind of format:

> nginx:
>
> ```
> enabled:
>     abc.com
>     xyz.com
> disabled:
>     test.com
>     test2.com
> ```

i DO NOT want to make the format like that:

> nginx::enabled:
>
> ```
> abc.com: {}
> xyz.com: {}
> ```
>
> nginx::disabled:
>
> ```
> test.com: {}
> test2.com: {}
> ```

How can i make my puppet script worked as expected. i also read Hiera document, as i know, it is also supported three kinds of lookup data: hiera, hiera_hash and hiera_array.
but i could not make it work as my expected following my yaml file format above

Sorry as i am very new with hiera.

Thanks in advanced.